# javascript: How do I convert Uint8Array data to a JS object

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to both Javascript and JSON worlds. I am wondering how I could convert an incoming Uint8Array data () to a JS object?
Any help / pointers please. Here's what I have done as an experiment.

```
// arr is uint8Array incoming data
function myConvertFunc(arr) {
  let str = "";
  for (var i=0; i<arr.byteLength; i++) {
    str += String.fromCharCode(arr[i]);
  }

  // Say, 'str' at this step looks like below :
  /* {"type": "newEvent", "content": {"rec": [{"id1": "1", "event": "3A=","payload": "EZm9ydW0ub="}]}} */

  var serializedData = JSON.stringify(str);
  let message = JSON.parse(serializedData);

  switch (message.type) {
    case "newEvent":
      log("In newEvent");
      break;
     .
     .
     .
    default:
      log("undefined message type");
  }
}
```

Contrary to my understanding, the default case log : **"undefined message type"** is show in my logs. Could someone please help me figure out my mistake here?

Comment: What is a "Uint8Array"?

Comment: The Uint8Array type represents an array of 8-bit unsigned integers. Not sure if this is the answer you are looking for

Comment: @MattBall: It's a [typed array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/Uint8Array

Comment: @Siddartha: Why do you need to put a JSON string into a typed array (or the other way round)?

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> var serializedData = JSON.stringify(str);
> let message = JSON.parse(serializedData);
> ```

That means if there are no errors that `str === serializedData` (or at least two equal-looking objects).

> Say, 'str' at this step looks like below:
>
> ```
> {"type": "newEvent", "content": {"rec": [{"id1": "1", "event": "3A=","payload": "EZm9ydW0ub="}]}}
> ```

Now, if `str` is the JSON string then you just want

```
var message = JSON.parse(str);
```

Currently, you did JSON-encode and then -decode the JSON string, with the result that `message` was the string again and its `type` property was `undefined`.

Comment: Well, this is what I have tried at the very beginning. When I JSON.parse(str), I get the error : "JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data". Hence unsure of this error, resorted to the code snippet that I first posted. But thanks though for clarifying.

Comment: Then probably your JSON string got amended with some invalid characters. Do a `console.log(str)` to make sure it is valid - not sure where you got your uint8array from and what else it might contain.

Comment: Thanks for identifying the issue. Indeed there was an extra character that was putting off JSON.parse(...). Now the issue is fixed. Appreciate your time.